# Greedy algorythm for rich-neighbor edge coloring of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, greedy

In an edge coloring, an edge e is called rich if all edges adjacent to e have different colors. An edge coloring is called a rich-neighbour edge coloring if every edge is adjacent to some rich edge. The smallest number of colors for which there exists such a coloring is denoted by X′rn(G). I'm interersted in a greedy algorythm that finds such a coloring. (The graph representation I'm using is a list of neighboring vertices)

I am getting stuck when it comes to traversing back when I find that the current coloring can't satisfy my conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your approach sounds like classical backtracking. But without seeing your code we cannot help.

Comment: Sorry, I will add the code, but in it's current state it does not work.

Comment: say we have a,b,c with edges ab and bc, and both edges the same color. Can you confirm this is a rich neighbor edge coloring?